# data-target button attribute change via vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

Ive got button that is closing bootstrap modal as below:

```
<button id="back_offer_button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addOffer">Go back</button>
```

I want to be able to dynamic change data-target via vanilla javascript to different location:

For example now is

```
data-target="#addOffer"
```

I want to change it to

```
data-target="#addDifferentOffer"
```

So I tried to get this button:

```
var backOfferButton = document.getElementById('back_offer_button');
```

And then:

```
backOfferButton.data-target = "#addDifferentOffer" <?>
```

This of course doesn't work. How should it be written correctly?

Comment: `backOfferButton.setAttribute('data-target', '#addDifferentOffer')`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The right way to manage **[`data-* attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** is by using `dataset` :

```
var backOfferButton = document.getElementById('back_offer_button');
backOfferButton.dataset.target = "#addDifferentOffer";
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var backOfferButton = document.getElementById('back_offer_button');

console.log(backOfferButton.dataset.target);

backOfferButton.dataset.target = "#addDifferentOffer";

console.log(backOfferButton.dataset.target);
```

```html
<button id="back_offer_button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addOffer">Go back</button>
```

Comment: This is also the right way, thank you again for your help

Comment: Heads up for compatibility with old browsers (if you target them), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thank you for your suggestion, I've changed the accepted answer. I'm beginner so I cannot make this kind of decisions correctly yet

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow world, glad I could helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as stated in the comment also, the general way of setting/getting HTML attribute values is by using the `setAttribute()`,`getAttribute()` methods.

So , you would do something like:

`let element = document.getElementById('#someId');
 element.setAttribute('name-of-the-attribute', value);`

Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)